# How to define a chi2 value function for arbitrary function?

Tags: python, scipy

I am doing some data fitting using the pyminuit Python bindings for the minuit minimisation code (http://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/). The minimiser accepts a function and uses introspection to extract the parameters to be minimised. In general, I want to minimise the chi squared value for a dataset given a particular function to describe the dataset.

My question: Is there a way to define a chi squared function which, given an arbitrary function with varying numbers of parameters, returns a function which gives the chi squared value for that function *and* only contains the parameters to be minimised in the function argument specification?

Example:

```
from scipy import *
import minuit
# Generate some data to fit
data_x = arange(50)
noise = 0.3
data_y = data_x**3 + normal(0.0, noise)
# Fit function, e.g. a cubic
fit_func = lambda x, a1, a2, a3, a4: a1 + a2*x + a3*x**2 + a4*x**3

# Minimisation function e.g. chi squared
# Note this has only the parameters to be minimised in the definition (eg not data_x)
min_func = lambda a1, a2, a3, a4: sum( (fit_func(data_x, a1, a2, a3, a4) - data_y)**2 / noise**2 )
```

THIS is where I'd like to write something like `min_func = make_chi2(fit_func)`. I don't know what to do as `data_x` and `data_y` are only defined outside of the function. The rest of the minimisation routine, for completeness, looks like:

```
# Initialise minimiser object with initial values
m = minuit.Minuit(min_func, {'a1': 1.0, 'a2': 1.0, 'a3': 1.0, 'a4': 1.0})
# Run minimiser
m.migrad()
# Print minimised values - example output
print m.values
>>> {'a1': 0.000, 'a2': 0.000, 'a3': 0.000, 'a4': 1.000}
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: I'd call the fact that pyminuit extracts the parameters only by introspection and does not allow to explicitly name them an at least questionable design on the part of pyminuit.  Would they allow to give the parameters explicitly, your problem would be trivial to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since PyMinuit uses introspection, you have to use introspection, too.  `make_chi_squared()` could be implemented like this:

```
import inspect

chi_squared_template = """
def chi_squared(%(params)s):
    return (((f(data_x, %(params)s) - data_y) / errors) ** 2).sum()
"""

def make_chi_squared(f, data_x, data_y, errors):
    params = ", ".join(inspect.getargspec(f).args[1:])
    exec chi_squared_template % {"params": params}
    return chi_squared
```

Example usage:

```
import numpy

def f(x, a1, a2, a3, a4):
    return a1 + a2*x + a3*x**2 + a4*x**3

data_x = numpy.arange(50)
errors = numpy.random.randn(50) * 0.3
data_y = data_x**3 + errors

chi_squared = make_chi_squared(f, data_x, data_y, errors)
print inspect.getargspec(chi_squared).args
```

printing

```
['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4']
```

Comment: I had something like this written, but this is much more concise and neat. Thanks!