# Is it possible to minimise with PyMinuit using a dictionary for parameter reference

Tags: python

Is it possible to carry out a [PyMinuit](http://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/) function minimisation by passing a dictionary of parameters to the minimiser?

For example, the usual use of PyMinuit would be called using something like:

```
def f(x, a, b): return a + b*x

def chi2(a,b):
    c2 = 0.
    for x, y, yerr in data:
        c2 += (f(x, a, b) - y)**2 / yerr**2
    return c2

m = minuit.Minuit(chi2)
m.migrad()
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7927670/how-to-define-a-chi2-value-function-for-arbitrary-function), I understand PyMinuit uses introspection to determine the parameters x and y (but I am not entirely sure what that means). Ideally, I would like to be able to do something like:

```
p = dict()
p['x'] = 0.
p['y'] = 0.

def f(x,a,b): return a + b*x

def chi2():
    c2 = 0.
    for x, y, yerr in data:
        c2 += (f(x, a, b) - y)**2 / yerr**2
    return c2

m = minuit.Minuit(chi2,**p)
m.migrad()
```

or even:

```
p = <dictionary of parameters + initial values>

model = <list containing strings representing functions e.g. 'a*b+a**2*x'>

data = x, y, yerr, model

def chi2():
    c2 = 0.
    for x, y, yerr, model in data:
        c2 += (eval(model,{"__builtins__":None},p) - y)**2 / yerr**2
    return c2

m = minuit.Minuit(chi2)
m.migrad()
```

I saw a work-around to a similar problem on the google groups [issues page](http://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/issues/detail?id=6) where they generated 'fake code' and 'fake functions' from an integer input (follow link to see). I tried something similar with my dictionary p:

```
class fake_code:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.co_argcount = len(p)
        self.co_varnames = tuple(p.keys())
        print tuple(p.keys())

class fake_function:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.func_code = fake_code(p)
    def __call__(self,*args):
        c2 = 0.
        print args
        for x, y, yerr in data:
            c2 += (f(x, a, b) - y)**2 / yerr**2
    return c2
```

but for some reason all the parameters are classed as 'fixed' and I can't seem to 'unfix' them.

I think it should be possible to do it this way, but I do not know enough about python to say if this is the best way, or even if it should be attempted. If anyone can shed some light onto this I'd be grateful to know. :)

Comment: Introspection is the act of self-examination. In a programming language, it's the ability to examine something to determine what it is, what it knows, and what it is capable of doing. In this case it probably refers to being able to determine names of the arguments to the function and where they're used in its code.

Comment: It looks to me like your first example, `minuit.Minuit(chi2,**p)`, where `p` is a dictionary might work since it is very similar to the `minuit.Minuit(f, x=10, y=10)` example shown at the first link. Have you tried it? If it doesn't then it might be possible make it work by generating some very simple "fake code" from the dictionary so that it was exactly like that first example using the technique for doing that in the latter part of your question. My advice is that you try doing those and, if neither work (and you can't figure out why), ask a another more specific question here.

Comment: That particular example (the first one) doesn't work and give a 'no parameters' error. I've done a bit more reading and I think this is because PyMinuit uses introspection to assign the parameters it will update from the arguments the input function, in this case `chi2`, requires. In the first example, `chi2` takes no arguments, so no parameters are assigned. In the second example, all the parameters end up 'fixed' and I haven't yet figured out how, or why.

Comment: Since a `minuit.Minuit(chi_squared, **p)` won't work, I was going to suggest that you make a template for only it and just add the argument names and values to that with `exec` at runtime, as opposed to the whole `chi_squared()` function definition as you've done in your answer.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean - is it that I should use `exec` to make `minuit.Minuit(chi_squared)` at run-time? I can sort of see how it could add additional arguments like `limits_a1=(lower,upper)` to the minimisation routine but I'm struggling with the parameters. Is there any chance you could give me an example so I can see?

Answer (score 1):

OK, I don't like answering my own questions, but I think I've found a solution using `exec`. If one defines the `chi2` function in a template and builds it at run-time with a function `make_chi_squared` then it is possible. The solution I've managed to come up with is shown below.

```
import minuit
import numpy

chi_squared_template = """
def chi_squared(%(params)s):
    li = [%(params)s]
    for i,para in enumerate(li):
        p[l[i]] = para
    return (((f(data_x, p) - data_y) / errors) ** 2).sum()
"""

l = ['a1','a2','a3','a4']

p = dict()
p['a1'] = 1.
p['a2'] = 1.
p['a3'] = 1.
p['a4'] = 1.

def make_chi_squared(f, data_x, data_y, errors):
    params = ", ".join(l)
    exec chi_squared_template % {"params": params}
    return chi_squared

def f(x,p):
    return eval('a1 + a2*x + a3*x**2 + a4*x**3',
                {"__builtins__":locals()},
                p)

data_x = numpy.arange(50)
errors = numpy.random.randn(50) * 0.3
data_y = data_x**3 + errors

chi_squared = make_chi_squared(f, data_x, data_y, errors)

m = minuit.Minuit(chi_squared)
m.printMode = 1
m.migrad()
print m.values
p = m.values
print p
```

It's a bit messy, and I'm not sure if its the best way of handling this type of problem, but it works!

Answer (score 1):

This following is largely untested, which I usually try to avoid doing, but am making an exception to better explain to you the simplified way I referred to in my comments that might work for this. It's based on the first example shown [here](http://code.google.com/p/pyminuit/#Examples).

```
import minuit

def minuit_call(func, **kwargs):
    CALL_TEMPLATE = "minuit.Minuit({0.__name__}, {1})"
    arg_str = ', '.join('{}={}'.format(k, v) for k,v in kwargs.iteritems())
    return eval(CALL_TEMPLATE.format(func, arg_str))

def f(x, y):
    return ((x-2) / 3)**2 + y**2 + y**4

m = minuit_call(f, x=0, y=0)
m.migrad()
```

As you can see, the template used is fairly trivial and creating it didn't require manually translating any of the code in the body of the function to be minimization into a formatting string.

Answer (score 1):

Might be late for answer. Try this out iminuit. I wrote it because of the lack of this specific feature among others.

http://iminuit.github.com/iminuit/

See example how you would write a generic cost function here:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/iminuit/iminuit/master/tutorial/hard-core-tutorial.ipynb

However, although it's easy to write a chi^2/likelihood function, it's already written for you in probfit

http://iminuit.github.com/probfit/